# Unable import text using importxml and xpath inside div

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

i'm Using Google Sheets with **IMPORTXML** to scrape a download count information from a japanese website via **XPath** in google sheet.  I want to save the number/text inside [this red box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EbwX.png)

here's the link
https://www.photo-ac.com/main/detail/4465781?title=%E3%82%A2%E3%82%B2%E3%83%8F%E8%9D%B6%E3%81%A8%E3%83%92%E3%83%A3%E3%82%AF%E3%83%8B%E3%83%81%E3%82%BD%E3%82%A6

here's my function

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.photo-ac.com/main/detail/4465781?title=アゲハ蝶とヒャクニチソウ", "/html/body/div[17]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[7]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]//text()")
```

the function doesn't work? why?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tested your formula, I confirmed that an error of `Could not fetch url:` occurred. But, fortunately, when Google Apps Script is used, I confirmed that the URL can be requested using UrlFetchApp. So, in this answer, I would like to propose to use Google Apps Script. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet, and save it, and put a formula of `=SAMPLE("URL")` to a cell. If the function name is not found, please reopen the Google Spreadsheet and test it again. This script is used as the custom function.

```
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const value = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().match(/ダウンロード：.+/);
  if (!value) throw new Error("Value was not retrieved.");
  return value;
}
```

#### Result:

When above script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script is for the current HTML of the URL of `https://www.photo-ac.com/main/detail/4465781?title=アゲハ蝶とヒャクニチソウ`. And, when the structure of HTML of the URL is changed, above script might not be able to be used. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)